# Java 8 - How to filter in java 8 to get results from different categories of Dish Type?

Tags: java-8

I am new to **Java 8** and looking to do something interesting here. Actually looking to get the **Highest Caloric Dish** from Each `Dish.Type`.

I tried something below, but its giving me all the values from the `Dish.Type.`

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Dish {
    public enum Type { MEAT, FISH, OTHER }

    private final String name;
    private final boolean vegetarian;
    private final int calories;
    private final Type type;

    public static final List<Dish> menu =
            Arrays.asList( new Dish("pork", false, 800, Dish.Type.MEAT),
                           new Dish("beef", false, 700, Dish.Type.MEAT),
                           new Dish("chicken", false, 400, Dish.Type.MEAT),
                           new Dish("french fries", true, 530, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("rice", true, 350, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("season fruit", true, 120, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("pizza", true, 550, Dish.Type.OTHER),
                           new Dish("prawns", false, 400, Dish.Type.FISH),
                           new Dish("salmon", false, 450, Dish.Type.FISH));
}
```

Looking to get result - get highest Caloric Dish from each different Dish Type.

I tried below, but gives all elements from the same dish type. Any pointers ?

```
List<Dish> truncatingStream = Dish.menu.stream().filter(d -> d.getCalories() > 300).limit(3).collect(toList());
        truncatingStream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Map<Type, Dish> map = menu.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Dish::getType,
                    Function.identity(),
                    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Dish::getCalories))));
```

You need to collect to a `Map` where key is `Type` and value is `Dish`. When you encounter two dishes of the same `Type` - you `merge` them *or* you take the max, according to the `Comparator.comparing(Dish::getCalories))` -meaning the one that has the most calories. This is what :

```
 BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Dish::getCalories)))
```

merger is doing.